# How to set x:Name with FrameworkElementFactory in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, devexpress-wpf

I am creating a Datatemplate in code that is retrieved by a Datatemplate selector. I can not create the datatemplate in xaml due to some business rules. I am using Devexpress' PropertyGridControl with customs Property Definitions.

The datatemplate is overriding the PropertyDefinition's CellTemplate, therefore the control inside the template must have **x:Name = "PART_Editor"**. The control inside the datatemplate is a TrackBarEdit, but it could be any editor control.

Here is the code for my template builder:

```
private DataTemplate BuildTemplate()
    {
        var trackbarFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(MyTrackBar));
        trackbarFactory.SetValue(RangeBaseEdit.MaximumProperty, 5.0);
        trackbarFactory.SetValue(MyTrackBar.NameProperty,"PART_Editor");
        var trackbarTemplate = new DataTemplate
        {
            VisualTree = trackbarFactory
        };
        trackbarTemplate.Seal();

        var propDefinitionFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(PropertyDefinition));
        propDefinitionFactory.SetBinding(PropertyDefinitionBase.PathProperty,new Binding(nameof(PropertyStore.Name)));
        propDefinitionFactory.SetBinding(PropertyDefinitionBase.IsReadOnlyProperty,new Binding("Metadata.ForceReadOnly"));
        propDefinitionFactory.SetValue(PropertyDefinition.CellTemplateProperty,trackbarTemplate);
        var propDefinitionTemplate = new DataTemplate
        {
            VisualTree = propDefinitionFactory
        };
        propDefinitionTemplate.Seal();

        return propDefinitionTemplate;
    }
```

The control renders properly with all the bindings, but I can not figure out how to set **x:Name** through the frameworkElementFactory. I have tried to set **FrameworkElement.NameProperty** and even to inherit TrackbarEdit to create a new DependencyProperty mapped to x:Name via **RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute** but it does not work.

As a consequence the editor rendered does not update the bound property's value.

Comment: Use XamlReader instead, FrameworkElementFactory is Depricated.

Comment: I saw that and I will explore that way. Nevertheless assuming that is not an alternative, is it still possible with FrameworkElementFactory?

Comment: Try ((FrameworkElement)object).RegisterName

Comment: @sTrenat, never mind, found it's depricated in [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr that way is depracated indeed, MSDN doc for the class explicitly says that

Comment: @sTrenat the problem is that with FrameworkElementFactory I can not get access to the FrameworkElement =(

Comment: @taquion from trackbarTemplate you can make RegisterName